# Replying with a html page in HTTP Web Server using esp01 and ArduinoIDE

Tags: arduino-ide, web-server, http

Now there are many ways to reply with a webpage content to a user who is accessing the web server,
But Keeping in mind to use as less space as possible,
I was trying something new, Since i didnt got compilation error, I am a little confused as to what might be the error,

in `void data()` I am storing the html page and saving it in ROM,

```
void data()
{
  if(SPIFFS.exists("/login.html"))
  {
    Serial.println();
  }
  else{
    SPIFFS.begin();
    File f=SPIFFS.open("/login.html","w");
    String s="<html><head><title>AP</title><h1>Welcome to AP page</h1>\n";
    s+="</head><body><form name=\"/myform\" action=\"/login\" method=\"POST\">\n";
    s+="<input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" placeholder=\"username\"><br/>\n";
    s+="<input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" placeholder=\"password\"><br/>\n";
    s+="<input type=\"submit\" value=\"login\"></form></body></html>";
    f.println(s);
    f.close();
  }

}
```

Please correct the above lines if I wrote it wrong,
After that, 
I wrote some lines in `void setup()`

```
WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);//Only Access point
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);  //Start HOTspot removing password will disable security

  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP(); //Get IP address
  Serial.print("HotSpt IP:");
  Serial.println(myIP);

  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, handleRoot);      //Which routine to handle at root location
  server.on("/",HTTP_POST,handlelogin);
  server.onNotFound(handleerror);

  server.begin();
```

Now  I am calling `void handleRoot()` 
I want to send the page that I wrote and saved in the `/login.html` file.

so for that,

```
void handleRoot()
  {
    SPIFFS.begin();
    File f=SPIFFS.open("/login.html","r");
    server.send(200, "text/html",f.readStringUntil('EOF'));
  }
```

Now once I do this and execute and load the program in ESP01, it shows me nothing,
I have also tried sending `(String)f`, anything else I write is giving me an error,
This is compiling fine, but when I connect to the AP and open 192.168.4.1 in the browser i am not seeing anything, 
But when I wrote `server.send(200,"text/html",(String)f)`
I was getting 0, Any idea on what mistake I am making.

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by having one bit of your program save a file of static data to SPIFFS and then another bit read that file and send it?

Comment: Unless I format the device, I can remove the bit where I add those lines to save the HTML file. Like remove the block of that code later.

Comment: Why not use the IDE's SPIFFS tools to create the SPIFFS image with the file already on it?

Comment: What I am doing wrong? Can I send a response like this? Or do I have to write the full html code again

Comment: I suspect it's the `'EOF'` that you're reading until. That's looking for the letter `E` not the end of the file.

Comment: You should use `server.streamFile("text/html", f);`

Comment: Ok, but the problem is , it's  'end of office' today. Thanks for the info, I have to update tomorrow. Sorry

Comment: @WanStreet, did you see this example https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples/FSBrowser/FSBrowser.ino?

Comment: I will now.. I y

Comment: I commented further as an answer post, I needed to post an image, I still havent yet tried with server.streamFile() ... will work on that in a minute.

Comment: It looks like you never called data().

Comment: hmmm.. ok.. seems like it.. can you please tell me where to call the data(), sorry I am unable to follow..

Answer (score 1):

Small update, I used the same code for ESP8266 NodeMCU.

Sorry If I am posting this with wrong device number. But I tried that same code and uploaded it to ESP8266, it worked, and I am getting the AP webpage, that I am storing and sending the file. I will post it as an answer as I need to post an image.

The is the page that I get when using the HTML that I wrote:

> [image: Webpage]

So, this happened. I am confused as to why it didn't work with ESP01, plus I have to load the code every time I plug in the ESP01.

Comment: wrong spiffs size or spiffs not initialized on the first device?

Comment: initialization of spiffs meaning? like `spiffs.begin()` ?

Comment: upload or format() http://esp8266.github.io/Arduino/versions/2.0.0/doc/filesystem.html

Comment: ah ok.. I will have to check tomorrow..